# How do I remove a block with local.xml?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, xml

I am trying to remove a block named catalog.leftnav. After reading this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937018/magento-remove-block-using-update-xml

I created a local.xml file and put this in there-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
   <default>
     <remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
   </default>
</layout>
```

I added it into frontend/default/themename/layout

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Go to `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` then add this within :

```
<reference name="left">
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
</reference>
```

Clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

Check you package & theme layout in Magento admin.

Go to

> admin -> system -> configuration -> design.

Under layouts set the theme name.

This will fix your issue.

Comment: I will try that first thing in the morning. I am still learning Magento so could you give me a clue on why that would fix it?

Comment: Magento uses theme fallback algorithms, so it needs to know where your layout is placed. If you don't set layout in admin, it will use base layout. You have placed your layout files under your theme.

Comment: So I went in and the theme was in there and it was the correct one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below code to given file path

app/design/frontend/YourTheme/default/layout/local.xml

```
<default>
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
</default>
```

Comment: I went ahead and did that, but still it appears.

Comment: check local.xml file path as per given above.

Answer (score 0):

is your theme is part of design fallback.

If yes then this code will work otherwise it will not going to call in case of that you need to  add your layout and theme name under, but be sure otherwise your old theme will not going to fall back

```
admin->system->configuration->design
```

Comment: It is there. Any other ideas?